# Can't edit to change "code" format to "quote" format

Tags: discussion, editing

I noticed a [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199289/when-is-a-subject-considered-plural) that formatted an example sentence as preformatted (monospace) text, rather than as a block quote. I tried to change it, but couldn't, because "edits must be at least 6 characters."

I'm just wondering if this type of edit ought to be allowed.

Comment: To overcome the character limit, use italics, write the word it's as "it is", improve the generic title, add a space, and/or a tag. There are ways of getting round this limit. That said, I'm not keen about bumping a question that has only attracted 23 views in nearly three years, but each to his or her own.

Answer (score 4):

It's unlikely that we'll change the requirement for edits, but mods (and higher rep users, maybe?) can make small edits. If there is truly nothing more to edit, you can flag it for mod attention and let us know what needs changing. I already made the change you cited here.

Comment: Are you suggesting users flag for a moderator's attention to make edits? (O.o)

Comment: Just the teeny ones that would bug me personally if I knew they existed. If they are regular-sized edits, they can do it themselves.

Comment: In that case, expect a lot of teeny weeny edit requests coming your way. I really disagree with using mod flags for this sort of thing.

Comment: @NVZ hardly seems fair to affect *all* mods - next feature request, *targeted* flags, for passive-agressive flag [DDOS](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/distributed-denial-of-service-attack)ing

Comment: I will be floored if there is an increase in teensy edit flags.

Comment: Barely calling it a workaround, I found I could replace six characters for the sake of one in need of change.  That way, I changed six.

Comment: The [“edit questions and answers” privileges page](/help/privileges/edit) contains a wealth of information.  (1) Users with ≥2000 reputation, who can make unilateral *edits* (in contrast to *suggested edits*, which must be approved), can make arbitrarily small edits.  (2)  “**Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** – try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.”  You’ve got to consider the possibility that, if an edit perturbs fewer than six characters, it’s too tiny and too trivial to be worth making. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … If you’re sure your change is important, go over the entire post with a fine-toothed comb and try to find other things that can be improved. Asking for help is the last resort if (a) you’re sure that the edit is critical, and (b) you really can’t find six characters to improve. Even then, you should probably just post a comment describing what needs changing, and wait for a 2K+ user to do the edit. (And, if you don’t have even the 50 rep that you need to post a comment, you should probably think long and hard about whether you may be in over your head.)

Answer (score 3):

Usually I (and others like myself) edit out such blatant misuse of monospace text whenever I chance upon them within the 'active' (or 'newest') question feed.

The question you link to, it's had only about 20 views in 3 years.

Your aim here as I understand is merely to remove the monospace formatting, and even if you'd wanted it reopened, I don't think it needs to be, because it is closed as a duplicate of a much better received question.

So even though 'there are workarounds' for getting past the 6-characters minimum requirement for edits, I'd suggest against waking up the dead.